# Bind TabControl page selection to a set of RadioButtons with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, radio-button

I have four `RadioButton`s in one column and a `TabControl` in another column with four tab pages.
What is the best way to bind the `SelectedIndex` of the `TabControl` to the checked state of the `RadioButton`s to allow users to select a tab page by clicking the `RadioButton`?
Ideally, I want to use Microsoft CommunityToolkit.MVVM.

Comment: Just add 4 bool properties in your view model and bind them to RadioButton-ToggleButton.IsChecked and your each TabItem-TabItem.IsSelected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the [`IsSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabitem.isselected?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property of `TabItem` to the [`IsChecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property of `RadioButton`:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
      <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" GroupName="TabRadioButtons" Content="Tab 1"/>
      <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" GroupName="TabRadioButtons" Content="Tab 2"/>
      <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton3" GroupName="TabRadioButtons" Content="Tab 3"/>
      <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton4" GroupName="TabRadioButtons" Content="Tab 4"/>
   </StackPanel>
   <TabControl Grid.Column="1">
      <TabItem Header="Tab 1" IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton1}"/>
      <TabItem Header="Tab 2" IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton2}"/>
      <TabItem Header="Tab 3" IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton3}"/>
      <TabItem Header="Tab 4" IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton4}"/>
   </TabControl>
</Grid>
```